# Set as start page a html file in MVC4 Doesn't change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi guys i added a **html** file to my project in MVC ,and i set this page as a start up ,and now i want to change my default route to another view in MVC .

So i added this code to my **global.asax** but it didn't work :

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Any idea .Thank you

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470416/how-to-set-a-default-page-on-an-mvc-app

Comment: if it didn't work, what error do you get? Do you have Account controller with login action? And login view for that action?

Comment: I don't gt any error .when i run my project the html page comes as a first page