# Change default page in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have created a new MVC project and whenever I start the project, "Index.cshtml" in Views is launched first. Where is this defined and how do i change it to some other page.

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470416/how-to-set-a-default-page-on-an-mvc-app

Comment: Check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470416/how-to-set-a-default-page-on-an-mvc-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for this setting, in global.asax.cs or in RouteConfig.cs under App_Start.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Change its default controller and action as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In the App_Start folder open RouteConfig.cs. Change the `defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }` to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way

- change the default maproute

  ```
  routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "ABC", action = "XYZ", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
  ```
- change the action index -> view name

  ```
  return View("ViewName")
  ```