# How can I hide/change URL in the starting page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, websecurity

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //routes.MapPageRoute("Uniquename", "Name to shown on Adddress bar AND for redirecting", "Physical Path to the page");
    routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "StoreFrontPage", "~/BestSeller.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("index", "MainPage", "~/index.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("ProductDetails", "DetailOfProduct", "~/ProductDetails.aspx");
}
```

Above codes helps me change the name of the url when i use "href" or "response.redirect" so when i open the first webpage  (the starting page) i could not hide the url.
i do not want users to see the name of the webpage.aspx file.
thanks for any advices/help!

Comment: What URL are you typing into the browser?

Comment: i didnt put it in a external server, its still in my IDE

Comment: the starting page would be index.aspx, but i want it to show as MainPage the moment i run the program/webpage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470416/how-to-set-a-default-page-on-an-mvc-app