# How to Set Default Page in MVC4 using Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Able to create Controller and Views on my ASP.NET MVC app.

When I start the application each time I have to type /index.

I read through posts which suggests to use  `routes.MapRoute(..`

But my Global.asax file does not contain route directly.

Do I need to use    `RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(..` instead.

Comment: In `MVC4` it's in `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Worked for me . You could put this in answer as answer. I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC4 the default routes where moved from:

`Global.asax`

To:

`App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`