# Hosting ASP.NET MVC Project on godaddy.com

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, hosting

Is there a way that I can run a ASP.NET MVC Project on Godaddy.com ?
I published the project and tried, but not working. 
It worked in IIS but not working in Godaddy. 
I am new on hosting in Godaddy. 
Please tell me the solution for that.

In Godaddy ASP.NET MVC Project, how to set the default start page ?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Get Windows Hosting Plan from Go Daddy to host your Asp.Net related project

**Step 2 :**

- Login to your  GoDaddy Account add new temporary domain to test your application
- Create a folder to publish your project build
- Create new FTP account
- If you have database create new SQL Server Database

For clear understanding Check [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-your-Asp-Net-mvc-website-on-godaddy-server/) from Step 1 to Step 12

**Step 3:**

This step is using `FileZilla` FTP software, if you want to use Visual Studio FTP then follow steps in [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-your-Asp-Net-mvc-website-on-godaddy-server/) article.

- Publish your project to [File System](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/francissvk/how-to-publish-Asp-Net-web-application-using-visual-studio-2/)
- Download FileZilla Client Using [FileZilla](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a397/upload-download-web-files-using-filezilla.aspx) FTP login to your GoDaddy FTP account and upload your project files and `dll's`.
- Type your temporary domain name in browser to check your hosted application , if you still get errors you can research and fix it or ask a new question related to your error.

Comment: Hai, In Godaddy ASP.NET MVC Project, instead of html we can set .cshtml page as the default start page for the MVC project ?   Please tell me how to prepare the start page in an MVC project....

Comment: Initially no changes  in `webConfig` , What i mean was if you get any error after hosting your mvc application to GoDaddy then it can be related to  `webConfig`. First try to host the application following the steps mentioned.

Comment: And to set the startup page in mvc we have to define routes check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc). If you are new to MVC ,check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) to learn from start. :)