# IIS does not run the project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

**IIS does not work in Visual Studio when all IIS installation is done. I may have made a mistake in one place but I do not know where it is.**

I will explain all the steps I have made. If you have the idea or have already received the error, if you know the solution, please share

**1 Step : Installing / activating IIS**

Picture Language : Turkish

[IIS Install - Windows10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X27Ju.jpg)

**2. Step : Verifying the operation of the localhost**

**[Localhost okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAyG6.jpg)**

I can see that IIS is working when I write localhost on the urll part of the browser

**3. Step : Adding project employee application to ISS - CREATE VIRTUAL DIRECTORY
That's all I've done. But I also get an error adding the project to IIS. I got the error screen below visual**

[application error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uvp2.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide how you deployed the application ? because it seems the iis is running fine the problem is in deployment or some configuration which is missing.

Comment: What is the authentication on your website? Are you using windows authentication?

Comment: @HanyHabib : Project settings > Web > Servers > Local IIS 

Project URL : http://localhost/Nop.Web 

Create Virtual Directory button click

Comment: @Wurd 
 
I do not use an extra authentication. Everything is in default settings. This is a project I am developing. Not a server either.

Comment: What kind of project? WebForms? MVC? Learn the typical URLs to access an ASP.NET web app, and then you can see if the address in your browser is correct, or not.

Comment: @LexLi MVC project

Comment: MVC projects have their URL pattern (controller/action for example), so you need to learn that before moving on. It can also be improved to support "/", if you do study how to configure URL routing. Simply ignore the answer below, as that's on the wrong path.

Comment: @LexLi Route settings do not show any problems. Actually, there was no such problem before. This error occurred after formatting to Windows

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc and compare to your project.

Comment: @LexLi No Problem. I know MVC routing well. There can not be a problem here. The problem is caused by IIS. But I can not find the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem is caused by the windows services. There was an error in the system files in Visual Studio. I reinstalled the Windows 10 Operating System and Visual Studio 2017. Problem solved. The problem is caused by the Windows 10 operating system files.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

As the mentioned screenshot error is Http Status Code 403.14 which means :

Server Error in Application "application name"
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
HRESULT: 0x00000000
Description of HRESULT : The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage

You are trying to browse the virtual directory not opening a page. To Enable Browsing you can :

1)Start IIS Manager. To do this, click Start, click Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then click OK.

2)In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then click the website that you want to modify.

3)In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.

4)In the Actions pane, click Enable.

Or Open Page Name as : Localhost/MyPage.aspx
Or Correct Route if MVC : http://localhost:12344/Home/
Here is Another Way to Do from Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is what microsoft mentions about the mentioned error with status code that you have sent :) ... One Final Suggestion redeploy again but with removing the dot in the url to be localhost/nopweb directly not dot in the middle

Comment: One last thing can you provide the web.config screen shot away from sensitive info.

Comment: There is no problem in web.config

Comment: I saw u mentioned now that you formatted the windows and installed the iis. Did u run theAspnet_regiis.exe command to be sure the .netframework currently used in your proj is registered in the iis ? If not give it shot try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx