# Whys is IISExpress giving 404, when server IIS works

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.7 on windows 10.

This issue is happening for Asp.net MVC 4 websites and Web Api 2.  Not for Aspnet.Core sites (so far)

Lately I have been having issues where I will be debugging a website and it will work fine then all of a sudden the next time you start the project up, it gives a 404 error.  The only way to fix the error is to use a different computer, create a new project and copy the info over.

Every time I start the debugger and get 404, this event is recorded.

> The directory specified for caching compressed content
>   C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool
>   is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.

Things I have tried.

- Uninstal VS / IISExpress and reinstall, including delete all folders in program files
- Create a new project and copy code over. (works, but then happens again later on)
- Use different computer. (works, but eventually that computer hits the issue too)
- Tried creating the temporary folder and giving "Everyone" full control of it.
- Tried changing port number and re-creating virtual directory
- Tried deleting entire solution folder and re-cloning repo.

The issue does not happen on the web servers, only locally.

Any idea on what is going on?  I can't find any configuration that is telling IIS to compress the files, so not sure why I keep seeing that error.

**Edit**

I determined that the application_start even in global.asax is never firing (StreamWriter code in it to log to a file in case debugger issue).  So I assume the 404 is because the routes never get registered.

I tried updating Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc to the latest 5.2.6.

**Edit 2**
So I found a workaround.  I installed IIS locally and publish to a folder and debug by attaching to the process.  If I point IIS directly at the project or use IIS within VS it doesnt work.

I think the issue is related to some dll goofiness, project seems to work once published.

[image]

**Edit 3**

Found the root of the problem.  I use Ubuntu/bash on windows.  Cloning the git repo through bash seems to be setting the permissions wrong.  If I clone through command line, the issue does not happen.  Now I need to figure out why bash is screwing up the file permissions.

Comment: What is the complete 404 error page? The event about compression can be irrelevant.

Comment: Added screenshot of 404.

Comment: Have you set a default page following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc?

Comment: Yes already tried that.  It has nothing to do with the project.  If I pull down the code to a different computer, it works for a bit.  I think some files on the computer are getting corrupted or something.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with VS2017 on Windows 10, default IIS Express and git for Windows. Suddenly iisexpress returns 404 on /Default.aspx!!??

Solution:

1. Close VS2017
2. Delete the git repository in the file system.
3. Open VS2017
4. Clone the git repo

this helped on my machine.