# How do i setup an asp.net web app on a windows iis

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis

I want to deploy an asp.net web app on my windows 10 pc, it was developed by someone one another computer but am getting the error below

[image]

Comment: Well if you are trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC web app, you should learn that it by default won't serve "/" and you need to set a view there, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are hosting an application in VS IIS Express instead of IIS. To fix 403.14 for"/" please remember to register index controller for yor web application.

If you wanna host it in IIS, Please install IIS and asp.net module from Windows server->add role and feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules

Then you can create a website and publish release via VS web deployment tool.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Answer (score 0):

From the error above, it seems that you haven't setup your own default page. Maybe this post cant help you https://windowswebhostingreview.com/troubleshoot-403-error-when-publishing-asp-net-core/