# Standalone IIS Server Fails to start web application based on the start up url/ launch url/ default view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, view, routes, url-routing

We developed an ASP.NET MVC  version 5.2.7.0 application using the following technologies:

-ASP.NET MVC  version 5.2.7.0

-.NET Framework 4.6.1

-Visual Studio 2019

We have to deploy said application to the following environment that contains a standalone IIS Server:

-32-bit Environment

-Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Service Pack 1)

-IIS Version 7.5

- Also installed .NET Framework 4.6.1 Runtime and SDK

-8 GB RAM

It's a typical ASP.NET MVC setup and configuration:

> ```
> public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
> {
>     protected void Application_Start()
>     {
>         AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
>         GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
>         FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
>         RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
>         BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
>     }
> }
>
>
> public class RouteConfig
> {
>     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
>     {
>         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
>
>         routes.MapRoute(
>             name: "Default",
>             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
>             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
>         ); ................................... .................................................
> ```
>
> .........................................................

It works when I run it in Visual Studio 2019 debug mode because it shows the default landing page with Application title.

However, when I deploy it to the standalone IIS Server, and just click "Browse" in IIS Manager, I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>
> A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and
>   directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

It's really strange because the on the standalone IIS Server, the application in question has a bin directory that contains the Necessary files needed for ASP.NET MVC:

> System.Web.Helpers.dll
>   System.Web.Http.dll 
>    System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll 
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll 
>   System.Web.Optimization.dll 
>   System.Web.Razor.dll 
>   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
>   System.Web.WebPages.dll 
>   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll 
>   System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll 
>   System.Xml.XDocument.dll 
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll 
>   System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll 
>   System.Xml.XPath.dll 
>   System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll

Could someone please tell me how to resolve the aforementioned error on the standalone IIS SErver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set "Homepage" in Asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc) Visual Studio has the luxury to parse your code and know what to use as default page, but IIS don't.

Comment: Within the question, you will see my RouteConfig 's RegisterRoutes method already has "Default" route defined.  But, I still get "403.14 - Forbidden", "A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server."

Comment: Read the linked thread carefully. That route is different.

Answer (score 1):

The reason may be very simple, we need to enable certain windows features to support Asp.NET platform web application.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.