# How to deploy ASP.NET core web application to IIS on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

### 1.What I want to do

I am new to C# and now trying to deploy a "ASP.NET web application" to IIS.
I tried to follow the steps introduced in this website but instead of the view (Index.cshtml) showing, some directory list shows up when I test “Browse” from IIS.

https://www.guru99.com/deploying-website-iis.html

### 2.Current Problem

It is currently showing some directory list instead of the view (Index.cshtml).

[Showing a directory list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we7mH.jpg)

### 3.What I did

**STEP1.Create ASP.NET Core Application**

-After adding a project, I added a Controller(HomeController) and a View(Index.cshtml)
-After that I was able to access using IIS Express with URL "https://localhost:44320/Home/Index"

[STEP1.Create ASP.NET Core Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhd2D.jpg)

[STEP1.Success https://localhost:44320/Home/Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2cck.jpg)

**STEP2.Publish**
-Give a Target Folder and generate the application
-The destination I gave a path in “C\TempApp” (Sorry, the path in the image is wrong, I actually gave “C\TempApp”)

[STEP2.Publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yVJa.jpg)

**STEP3.Add new application in IIS**
-Give the Pysycal path " C:\TempWeb\Home\View "
-Give the host as “localhost”

[STEP3.Add new application in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg0Sj.jpg)

**STEP4.Test**
-Right click the new Application -> Manage Application -> Browse

[STEP4.Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y357c.jpg)

**STEP5.Fix Error**
Following the message shown in 403 screen, I enable “Directory Browsing” , then I  got the following result.

[STEP5.Fix Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we7mH.jpg)

#### 2021/1/27 19:00 add

I got advice to check the default page, and it seems the Default page was auto generated to point the View I created.

When I check the "Server Role" setting of IIS, I found ASP.NET and .NET 4.7 is not checked, and estimating that this might be the cause.

[IIS Server Role settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2J8g.jpg)

Comment: When you are new to something, always start with the official documentation, not some random posts on the internet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am sorry, I wrote "ASP.NET core" in my initial post, but it was actually "ASP.NET web application". In that case, will the link you told me still OK to follow? Or else, I found this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-iis?view=vs-2019 . Is there any advice which to follow ? (And actually I couldn't find an Official MS doc which shows the step of Publish mode "File")

Comment: Since you edited the question, the problem is rather clear now. All you need to add is a default page for this MVC web app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I checked the default document settings in "RouteConfig.cs" and there was already a setting there (I seems auto generated). And it seems working fine, since the default page is successfully shown using the "IIS Express" integrated in VS.

Another point I am worried is the components installed in IIS. I added a screenshot in the bottom of the question, but when I choose "Server Roles" for IIS, the ASP 4.5 and .NET 4.5 is unchecked. Does this have anything related to this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the asp.net core site in iis you have to install .net core hosting bundle and runtime.

you can download it from the below link according to your version:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the asp.net core site published folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I am sorry, I wrote "ASP.NET core" in my initial post, but it was actually "ASP.NET web application". My understanding is ".net core hosting bundle and runtime" is only required for ASP.NET "Core" only, is this correct ?

And I also updated my question, so if possible would you please take a look at the new version ?

Comment: @Tatsuya yes you are right hosting bundle is only needed for the .net core site. and to resolve your current issue you just need to set the default page for your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I checked the default document settings in "RouteConfig.cs" and there was already a setting there (I seems auto generated). And it seems working fine, since the default page is successfully shown using the "IIS Express" integrated in VS.

Another point I am worried is the components installed in IIS. I added a screenshot in the bottom of the question, but when I choose "Server Roles" for IIS, the ASP 4.5 and .NET 4.5 is unchecked. Does this have anything related to this issue ?

Comment: @Tatsuya yes try to enable asp 4.5 and .net 4.5

Comment: Yes this solved the problem. Thanks for your help.