# Cant Host .net application to iis server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-hosting

I was trying to publish dotnet MVC application to IIS .I created a site in that and opened in the browser .but it looks like this [image: this is the screenshot of site running]
how to run my app on IIS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set "Homepage" in Asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I believe you hit the famous 403.14 error page and then enabled directory browsing. Please follow the famous thread to set a default route for your MVC web app and disable directory browsing.