# Deploy ASP.Net MVC web app to IIS with 403.14 Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm using .NET Framework 4.8 and tried to deployed my web app to IIS but it showed the 403.14 error.

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

And then I enabled directory browsing. This time, it showed the directory listing instead. As I clicked the "Views" folder, it returned another error.

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internet Server Error
Handler "BlockViewHandler" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list
```

I have been finding solution for days but none of them worked...

EDIT: I started a new MVC project and tried to depoly it. It works perfectly. But it broke once I added new database using entity framework. Just guessing the problem comes from the database. Is there any configuration if I want to deploy a MVC app with db?

Comment: Have you set a homepage for your MVC web app? If not, get started from there please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc Roll back all previous changes you made and you should never enable directory browsing.

Comment: @LexLi I have set it in web.config `Home/Index`. It works on localhost.

Comment: it mostly happens when the user has no proper permission. check your permissions on the served directory by IIS. sometimes you need to add `IIS_IUSR` to the security tab of the properties of the directory to let IIS manage the files.