# ASP.NET Web Application ( .NET Framework 4.8) not running within IIS 10 on Windows Server 2022 Standard

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, windows-server, iis-10

I am wondering if anyone can help me, I am trying to run asp.net web application which is using .net 4.8 on Windows Server 2022 Standard with IIS 10 (on a virtual machine). I can see other questions but they are much older versions of IIS and Windows Server and do not resolve the issue. It appears that IIS is not recognizing or refusing to run .net 4.8.

When I deploy a site to IIS and then run it, it shows "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden", the logs do not clarify it there is an error. Just (main IIS Log)

```
2024-02-03 16:41:54 ::1 GET / - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/121.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - - localhost 403 14 0 1
```

Now the ASP.NET Web Application runs fine in Visual Studio and IIS Express. So I can rule out an issues with the ASP.NET Web Application.

To ensure IIS is / was working, I have tried adding a simple Index.html file which works fine, also after installing the .NET Core Hosting Bundle IIS can run .Net Core applications fine. It just will not run .net 4.8 ASP.NET Web Applications. Which is what I want it do

I followed:

[Microsoft's Configuring Steps for IIS and ASP.NET Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules) to no success either and I can not enable NET Extensibility as per screen shots below:

[image: Server Roles]

[image: Features]

[image: Install Failure]

Some questions I have seen here on stack overflow refer to NET Extensibility solving the issue but I can not add it.

Current configuration in IIS 10 but not working:

IIS settings:

[image: Application Pool]

[image: ISAPI & CGI]

Site IIS Log: (not helpful)

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2024-02-03 17:09:27
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2024-02-03 17:09:27 ::1 GET / - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/121.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - - localhost 403 14 0 17
2024-02-03 17:09:27 ::1 GET / - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/121.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - - localhost 403 14 0 4
```

To cover all angles, I installed Visual Studio on the server to see if that would be able to run a .Net 4.8 project to which it did, but still would not work within IIS 10. So it seems to be problem with the IIS 10 configuration.

I even tried to show detailed errors in the web.config still the same result of

[image: Failure]

I then tried installing ASP.NET modules by using the command line from [Microsoft's Configuring Steps for IIS and ASP.NET Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules)  still not working.

I wondering if someone could help me to get IIS 10 to run ASP.NET Web Applications (framework version: .net 4.8)

Comment: 1. Are you referring to "Windows Server 2022"? 2. Is this an ASP.NET MVC 4.x web app?

Comment: Sorry it is Windows Server 2022 Standard and I have updated it. Yes it will not run ASP.NET MVC 4.x web app's also

Comment: 403.14 is expected when you host ASP.NET MVC 4.x on IIS, because indeed it does not have a default page to show. Read classic posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc to learn what you should do.

Comment: Before installing .NET Framework 3.5, you need to remove the newer version of .NET Framework 4.8. Then reinstall .NET Framework. If your application is built using ASP.NET 3.5 and is not compatible with ASP.NET 4.8, you need to install ASP.NET 3.5.

Answer (score -1):

Is your project type set to 4.8, or something else like 4.81??

E.g. this:
[image]

So, if I set above to 4.8.1, then you need that version installed on the server.

The other issue? Are you running the site as a x32 bits, or a x64 bits?

In other words, are you using ANY CPU, or say x32 or x64 bits for the project settings?

I would consider forcing your project to run as x64 bits. Since you installed VS, and IIS Express works, then I'm betting this is a configuration issue, and something you missed in the setup of IIS here.

If you building to x32 bits, then of course in the app pool, you want to enable x32 bit applications (and I see you have).

Remember, any version of Visual studio BEFORE vs2022 was a x32 bit version (yes, you read this correct, vs2022 is the FIRST version of VS that is x64 bits). As a result, using ANY CPU would result (by default) result in a x32 bit version of your software (for any version of VS pre-2022).

With vs2022, ANY CPU for your project settings will now result in a x64 bit version of your project running (at least it does when you hit F5 to debug).

What this means and suggests is that you do NOT want to use ANY CPU for your project settings anymore.
Don't thus let the platform "guess" for you as to what the resulting project bit size it will "out of the blue" wind up running as.

So, now, force and "be 100% sure" of this issue. So, try forcing your project to x64 bits, build it. If that build's, then using the publishing wizard, publish to a local folder. Now delete everything in the wwwroot site folder, and then copy that folder to the root site folder you have on the server. And make sure while creating that local publish folder, you set publish options to x64 bits. If the publish to that folder works?

Then stop IIS, delete everything in the wwwroot folder, and then copy the published folder to that wwwroot folder (the sub folder used for that web site instance).

Now start IIS and see if the project runs.

And at the very least, I would set the project to .net 4.8, and not 4.8.1 as a test.